# Get current URL Javascript/Html

Tags: url, get

Could someone recommend a way to get page name from a url using JavaScript?

For instance if I have:

http://tulyita.hu/LikeGame/Game.html?like=100

I just need to get `"100"` string

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

how about this:-

```
var index = yourstring.lastIndexOf("=") + 1;
var filename = yourstring.substr(index);
```

Answer (score 1):

To TRY

```
alert(getURLParameters("http://tulyita.hu/LikeGame/Game.html?like=100","like"));
```

Others

> alert(getURLParameters("http://tulyita.hu/LikeGame/Game.html?like=100&share=4","share"));
>
> alert(getURLParameters("http://tulyita.hu/LikeGame/Game.html?like=100&hits=29","hits"));

Use this

```
   function getURLParameters(sURL , paramName) 
    {

    if (sURL.indexOf("?") > 0)
    {
       var arrParams = sURL.split("?");         
       var arrURLParams = arrParams[1].split("&");      
       var arrParamNames = new Array(arrURLParams.length);
       var arrParamValues = new Array(arrURLParams.length);     
       var i = 0;
       for (i=0;i<arrURLParams.length;i++)
       {
        var sParam =  arrURLParams[i].split("=");
        arrParamNames[i] = sParam[0];
        if (sParam[1] != "")
            arrParamValues[i] = unescape(sParam[1]);
        else
            arrParamValues[i] = "No Value";
       }

       for (i=0;i<arrURLParams.length;i++)
       {
                if(arrParamNames[i] == paramName){
            //alert("Param:"+arrParamValues[i]);
                return arrParamValues[i];
             }
       }
       return "No Parameters Found";
    }

}
```

REF:[How to get the value from the GET parameters?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/979975/how-to-get-the-value-from-url-parameter)